# How to redirect with Htaccess TO multiple sites?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been searching around to redirect my traffic TO multiple different sites but didn't find answers online.

Most of the google/stackoverflow results show the opposite (multiple domains/sites traffic to ONE site).

Can someone please help me how to do a round robin redirecting of traffic from a site to multiple sites? Example say there are 10 people who came to my site (www.randomrecipes.com) today:

Person 1 will be redirected to www.recipe1.com

Person 2 will be redirected to www.recipe2.com

Person 3 will be redirected to www.recipe3.com

Person 4 will be redirected to www.recipe1.com

Person 5 will be redirected to www.recipe2.com

Person 6 will be redirected to www.recipe3.com

Person 7 will be redirected to www.recipe1.com

Person 8 will be redirected to www.recipe2.com

Person 9 will be redirected to www.recipe3.com

and so on...

I would really appreciate help on any solution to accomplish this please!!!!

:)

Comment: This is more easily accomplished via a scripting language like PHP, since Apache doesn't have good ways of maintaining state between unrelated HTTP requests.

Comment: What other technologies do you have available, besides Apache built-in functionality?

Comment: You could also do it via JavaScript if you didn't require it to be absolutely bullet-proof, and could settle for randomness as opposed to a predictable sequential pattern. Are all those domains `www.recipeX.com` yours, or do you plan to redirect to sites you don't own?

Comment: Michael, I am using godaddys hosting so I think they have all of that available. (http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx)

I can do an index.html with a Javascript if thats what you are suggesting. I don't own the recipex.coms but I do own the original randomrecipes.com. This will not be used for spamming in case you are wondering. It will act as a fun project Im working on. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is strictly an apache thing (e.g. not using scripts, DNS, controllers, etc) then you can use a [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) directive and define a random map. The `RewriteMap` directive can **only** be defined in server or vhost config, so you'll get an error if you try to define it in an htaccess file.

In server/vhost config, define map:

```
RewriteMap recipes rnd:/path/to/file/servers.txt
```

In your `servers.txt` file:

```
random_server recipe1|recipe2|recipe3|recipe4|recipe5|recipe6|recipe7|recipe8|recipe9
```

(etc)

Then in either your server/vhost config or in the htaccess file in your **www.randomrecipes.com** domain's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?randomrecipes\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.${recipies:random_server}.com/ [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi,

Since I am using godaddy's hosting, I am assuming that I would not be able to edit the server or vhost configs correct? Is there another way I can do? I believe I am only granted the public directory at Godaddy.

Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @Chaz No, I don't think the basic hosting with godaddy allows you to define rewrite maps. And no, I don't think there's any other purely apache way to do this without access to the server/vhost config. You'll have to point it to a script (like php) that redirects for you.

Comment: got it. I'll have to look at PHP redirects then. Thank You!